# How to get the maximum of a calculated value in XQuery?

Tags: xml, max, xquery

I have many orders like the following:

```
<order id="1">
   <TargetPrice>100</TargetPrice>
   <Qty>2</Qty>
</order>
```

I need an Xquery to get the order with highest value (where value is TargetPrice*Qty)

How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sort the orders by descending value, and return the first element.

```
(
  for $order in //order
  let $value := $order/TargetPrice * $order/Qty
  order by $value descending
  return $order
)[1]
```

Comment: So i can order by a let variable? nice! Thank you!

Comment: @Jens Erat If there are many orders with highest values, the answer is not correct.

Comment: Indeed, and this also applies to @MichaelKay's answer. The OP asked about a single order, though.

Answer (score 2):

You might like to implement the function in D.6.1 of the Functions and Operators 3.1 specification. This is a bit longer-winded than the "sort and take the first" solution, but it might be faster (in principle it is streamable), and the code is highly reusable.

**D.6.1 eg:highest**

The function eg:highest returns the items having the highest value for the supplied function.

XSLT implementation

(snip)

XQuery implementation

```
declare function eg:highest(
                     $seq as item()*
                     $f as function(item()) as xs:anyAtomicType)
                  as item()* {
     fn:fold-left(
       fn:tail($seq), fn:head($seq),
       function($highestSoFar as item()*, $this as item()*) as item()* {
         let $thisValue := $f($this)
         let $highestValue := $f($highestSoFar[1])
         return
           if ($thisValue gt $highestValue)
             then $this
           else if ($thisValue eq $highestValue)
             then ($highestSoFar, $this)
           else $highestSoFar
       })
};
```

To find the employees with the highest salary, the function might be called as:

```
eg:highest(//employee, function($emp){$emp/salary})
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to use the [simple map operator `!`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-30/#id-map-operator) and calculate the product of `TargetPrice * Qty` for the sequence of items, and then select the [`max()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-max) value, and use in a predicate:

```
let $maxVal := max(//order ! (TargetPrice * Qty))
return //order[(TargetPrice * Qty) eq $maxVal]
```

Comment: That would give you the highest value V, but you would then need to go back over the orders to find the order that has value V.

Comment: Yes, didn't pay close enough attention. Thought he was asking for the value, not the `<order>` with the highest value.